# Text not visible in webkit browsers on Mac, but visible on all other browsers

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, webkit

I am having a weird problem where certain text is not visible in both Chrome and Safari on Mac.

In all other browsers the text is perfectly visible, and I have no clue why this is happening. I've debugged in Firebug and Chrome Developer tools without any success.

Here's an example:

Firefox
[image]

Chrome
[image]

UPDATE: Here is the Javascript:

```
function openProductInfo() {
    closeAllProductInfo();
    $('#overlay').show();
    $('#info').css({visibility: 'visible', opacity: 0});
    $('#info').animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
    $('#options a.info').addClass('active');
    infoVisible = true;
}

$('.info').click(function() {
    if (infoVisible) { 
        $('#info').animate({opacity: 0}, 250, function() {  
            closeAllProductInfo(); 
        }); 
    } else { 
        openProductInfo(); 
    }

    return false;
});

$('#overlay').click(function() {
    if (infoVisible) { 
        $('#info').animate({opacity:0}, 250, function() { 
            closeAllProductInfo(); 
        }); 
    }
});
```

Here is the live site:

http://fine-grain-2.myshopify.com/products/the-bowden-black-walnut

Comment: It works fine for me (Chrome 25, Windows)

Comment: Are you on a Mac @nhahtdh ?

Comment: I guess it is problem with font (just a hunch anyway). I don't have anyway to test.

Comment: @nhahtdh no, if the browser can't find a font it defaults to a standard font.

Comment: Try removing the animation and just leave out the opacity. Does that fix it?

Comment: works for me. windows chrome 25.

Comment: perhaps the problem is the javascript error? Uncaught ReferenceError: gifty is not defined main.js line 169?

Comment: No that is something else, but I should probably comment out the JS while I'm not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out what the problem was.

I am using `@font-face` fonts for this site, and for some reason when I used `AvenirLight` instead of `Avenir` for the body font it made the text associated with only CSS3 transitions and JavaScript transitions invisible.

I still don't know why this is happening, and why it is exclusively happening in webkit browsers on Mac.

**Lets try and figure this out!**

Here are my `@font-face` declarations:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: url("AvenirLTStd-Medium.otf") format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "AvenirBold";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: url("AvenirLTStd-Black.otf") format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "AvenirLight";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: url("12-Avenir-Light.ttf") format("opentype");
}
```

Here is where I declared the `body` `font-family`:

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999999;
    font-family: Avenir;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it in Chrome. The '#info' div seems to be hidden (visibility:hidden).
You might want to consider using 'display' rather than 'visibility'.

Comment: typing `$('#info').css({visibility: 'visible'});` into the console *does* show the text FWIW.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out. I believe that that JavaScript is changing it to ``visibility: 'visible'`` when the details link is clicked.

Comment: @ZachL Do you mean that it becomes visible in Chrome for Mac when you manually type in ``$('#info').css({visibility: 'visible'});``? The JS is supposed to be doing that... hmmm I'll look into it when I get home and am on my Mac. No Mac's at work :(

Comment: heh, I'm sorry - I somehow missed the "Mac" thing.  Might be a good thing to check regardless though..

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying a CSS3 `transition` property to the `#info` div that has a `visibility:hidden;` attribute applied to it, it will not show up even after you apply a `visibility: visible;` to it after a certain state.

I had this issue as well and I had to remove the `transition` property from that div. Try removing the CSS3 `transition` property and see if that works.